# How to get eigen vectors given matrix and eigen values in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I am writing my own function get eigen values and eigen vectors. I have used QR algorithm to extract eigen values. How do I get eigen vectors using diagonal eigen value matrix D and original matrix A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use `eig`, you can solve the matrix equation like so:

```
V=zeros(size(A));
for i=1:length(A)
    V(:,i)=null(A-eye(size(A))*D(i,i));
end
```

Comment: Awesome!!  Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I can't make this code work. The null function is turning up an empty matrix and I get the error `Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix.`

Comment: Hmmm works for me. If I create a 3x3 square matrix `A`, use `[~,D]=eig(A)` to get the eigenvalues, then run the code in my answer, I get the same as running `[V,D]=eig(A)`. Odd.

Comment: Oops.  I had the wrong eigenvalues laying around in D. Thanks.

Comment: @nispio How did you fix the rectangular matrix error.  It works with eigen values returned by eig but the same data generated by me is not working?

Comment: @codepk I just used `[~,D]=eig(A)` like David recommended.  Maybe you should compare your eigenvalues to the ones generate by `eig` to see what the differences are.

Comment: It is exactly same still does not work.  Updated question with output.

Comment: If your eigenvalues are in a vector, then change `D(i,i)` to `D(i)`.

Comment: @David I tried that still the same error.  Does null() not work with user content?  Updated function above.

Comment: It should do. Maybe there is a problem with repeated eigenvalues though, in which cases `null` will probably give more than vector as a basis for a eigenspace which is not one-dimensional. Can you check for repeated eigenvalues?

Comment: @David It is a 10x10 matrix and I have list the 10 eigen values returned by my function and matlab (both match).  There does not seem to be any duplicates.  Provided matrix a above.

Comment: When I use your matrix, it all works and I get the same results as `eig(A)`. Sorry I can't help more, I'm stumped.

Comment: @David I think the problem is that the answers match only upto the 11th digit.

Comment: Yes they are not exactly the same due to computer precision issues. Is it working properly now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40288/discussion-between-codepk-and-david)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the eigenvalues in order to get the eigenvectors. Just use:

```
[V,D] = eig(A);
```

Comment: I am writing my own function get eigen values.  I have used QR algorithm to extract eigen values.  How do I get eigen vectors using diagonal eigen value matrix and original matrix?